# Printing arabic value to console passed from URL

Tags: jsp, arabic

I am using below code to print the arabic value to console but it is giving junk values i have tried using so many ways but nothing worked, can anyone please help me out. Below is my code.    URL is as below     `smsapi.jsp?SENDER=Interner&MOBILE=&TEMPLATEID=0&MSG=مرحبا شباب&DC=8`

```
<jsp:scriptlet>    
   ServletContext context = getServletContext();
   String MESSAGE = null;      
   MESSAGE =new String(request.getParameter("MSG").getBytes(),"Cp1256");            out.println("Message**"+MESSAGE); 
</jsp:scriptlet>   </form> </html>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What programming language are you using? Please tag the question with the that language.

Comment: Why dp you get the parameter value, convert it to bytes, then convert those bytes back to a string. Why not just get the parameter?

Comment: Hi cirosantilli -- I am using jsp and want to get the arabic value which i am passing through URL and once i get that i can insert to DB using java

Comment: Hi  Raedwald, Can you please provide brief on the information you provided